# How can I convert a List<T> to a List<I> Where T implements Interface I?

Tags: c#

What is the best way to convert a `List<T>` to a `List<I>` Where type T implements Interface I?

It looks like I can not do an explicit conversion like this:

```
List<T> myListOfT;
List<I> myListOfI = (List<I>)myListOfT
```

;

Comment: All it took to find the duplicate was to google "c# list interface to list class", you should research before posting questions. Also, your question title and body are opposite, which one are you looking for?

Comment: You changed what you wanted, so I changed the duplicate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Linq `IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)`. It casts the elements of our first collection to the type you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
List<I> myListOfI;
List<T> myListOfT = myListOfI.Cast<T>().ToList();
```